# emacs jruby config -- using java

Tags: java, emacs, jruby, mode

Is anyone using Jruby in emacs? I have setup emacs and it works perfectly for ruby code using jruby. However notice that java code isn't executing from within emacs. I have installed mode-compile and all my code except for java in jruby.

Been searching options for Java and of course found JDEE, noticed in a previous java specific thread however concerns with JDEE [What is the best way to do Java development in Emacs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156529/what-is-the-best-way-to-do-java-development-in-emacs/5790657#5790657) age/not developed/works only for Java5 etc.

I found another emacs how-to http://zarb.org/~gc/html/java-emacs.html noted the date it was posted was 2005 and the author advised to use Eclipse for Java.

Has anybody got suggestion on using Jruby in emacs?

Comment: Can I update the question to be; If I don't use mode-compile to evaluate my jruby scripts what good alternative to evaluate scripts in emacs?

Comment: Sure, just click 'edit' up there ^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Malabar-mode](https://github.com/espenhw/malabar-mode) is the only real alternative to JDEE(especially for Maven based projects). I'm not sure how it will fit into your JRuby development toolchain, though. Another more general solution would plain old java-mode + CEDET + [emacs code browser](http://ecb.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Well in emacs 23.3 cedet and java-mode are standard and I already have ECB installed too. Must just be a configuration issue I think. It outputts C:/cygwin/bin\ruby.exe -w c:/MyRuby/newtest.rb  I need to change the ruby to jruby. (NB I don't have matz Ruby installed) just jruby

Comment: I know my jruby environment variable is set okay as Geany with jruby -c "%f" runs the same script perfectly.

Comment: Looking at compiler-mode's source I noticed there is a ruby-command variable, with default value "ruby". Try something like (setq ruby-command "jruby.exe") and I think that will do the trick.

Comment: Awsome for me neeeded to drop the exe bit and it works. So working for me (setq ruby-command "jruby").